# How to calculate Standard Deviation in Zonal Analysis Using Python

Tags: pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I am attempting to use the following code to calculate standard deviation:

```
QgsZonalStatistics (QgsVectorLayer *polygonLayer, QgsRasterLayer *rasterLayer, const QString &attributePrefix="", int rasterBand=1, QgsZonalStatistics::Statistics)
```

But it is only giving mean and count. How do I get SD?

Comment: In my answer you have a complete code for getting only standard deviation or all statistics.

Answer (score 2):

For this situation:

[image]

complete code for getting only standard deviation is:

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()
provider = layers[1].dataProvider()

path = provider.dataSourceUri()

zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(layers[0], path,"", 1, QgsZonalStatistics.StDev)

zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

If you want all statistics, change suffix **StDev** for **All**.

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS, attributes table now shows a new calculated statistic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the API documentation for [QgsZonalStatistics](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsZonalStatistics.html). There is stated, that you can use flags to indicate which statistic you want to include. A complete list can be found in [this section](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsZonalStatistics.html#a2197714be9eb23e1d1ddeaa358b19136).

So you would do something like this:

```
myRasterLayer = 'C\path\to\raster\my_raster.tif'
QgsZonalStatistics(myPolyLayer, myRasterLayer, "prefix", 1,     stats = Statistics( Count | Sum | Mean| StDev) )
```

Where *myPolyLayer* is your input Polygone, *myRasterLayer* is the path to your raster file  from which you want to get the statistics, *prefix* a prefix for your attributes (can be empty), 1 stands for the rasterband you are looking in and *stats* determine the flags.

Comment: using zonalstats =qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(vectorlayer, rasterfile, 'zo_', 1, QgsZonalStatistics::( Count | Sum | Mean| StDev) )                                      zonalstats.calculateStatistics(None)    but showing error

Comment: @User18 could you add the error msg to your question so we can have a look?

Comment: Error: AttributeError: type object 'QgsZonalStatistics' has no attribute 'statistics'

Comment: @User18 did you have a capital 'S'  in stats = **S**tatistics( ... )?

Comment: @LaughU Your proposal doesn't work because second parameter must be a path to raster layer (not a **QgsRasterLayer** object).

Comment: @xunilk thanks for your input :) I changed my answer accordingly